# Trouble connecting pgadmin AWS-RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I've created an AWS RDS database instance and I've created a new server connection on pgAdmin.  It's connecting but when I click on the database I get the below error message.  What kind of things could I be doing wrong?  ( I get the same error on PSQL too)

" The operation or option is not available
could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Credential for asked mech-type mech not found in the credential handle
FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "86.159.85.29", user "postgres", database "rdsadmin", SSL on
FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "86.159.85.29", user "postgres", database "rdsadmin", SSL off"

Comment: Can you post the `psql` command you are using? It looks like you're trying to connect to the `rdsadmin` database, which is likely incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You must use SSL when authenticating via RDS IAM authentication. The message you're receiving hints at this by saying `SSL off`.

Comment: This was NOT clear to be thank you!